# Como utilizar overlay em um dialog dentro de um window no Kendo UI?

Tags: html, css, scss, kendo-ui, angular-kendo

Atualmente utilizo o [Kendo Ui Angular](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui)

Atualmente estou tentando utilizar dentro de uma window um componente que chama um dialog, porém meu dialog não está aplicando o efeito de opacidade de overlay, tendo atualmente este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhando a arvore dom através do inspecionar eu consigo atingir o meu efeito esperado alterando a propriedade da classe `.k-window .k-overlay` para `opacity: 0.5`:

```
.k-window .k-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Tendo então este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei adicionar na minha classe um id:

```
<kendo-dialog id="dialogConf" title="Confirmação" *ngIf="opened" (close)="closeDialog(false)" [minWidth]="250" [width]="450">
    <p style="margin: 30px; text-align: center;">Confirma o cancelamento?</p>
    <kendo-dialog-actions>
        <button kendoButton (click)="closeDialog(false)">Não</button>
        <button kendoButton (click)="closeDialog(true)" primary="true">Sim</button>
    </kendo-dialog-actions>
</kendo-dialog>
```

E então aplicar no `.scss` do meu componente:

```
#dialogConf.k-window .k-overlay {
    opacity: 0.5!important;
}
```

Também tentei:

```
.k-window .k-overlay::shadow {
    opacity: 0.5!important;
}
```

**@Edit:**

Consegui resolver através do código:

```
::ng-deep .k-window .k-overlay {
    opacity: 0.5!important;
}
```

Porém li que em breve esse pseudo seletor será removido em breve pois passa por cima da proteção de isolamento de estilos e isso potencialmente pode incentivar más práticas de uso, portanto deixo a pergunta aberta caso houver uma solução melhor.

Comment: se quiser resolver com gambiarra pega esse modal que vc colocou o ID e coloca um box-shadow nele assim box-shadow: 0 0 0 4000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); Se vc achar que te serve como resposta me fala que eu monto um exemplo pra vc. Outra opção é vc mudar o z-index do modal maior que está abaixo para ele ficar por baixo do overlay quando vc abrir um modal dentro do outro

Comment: @hugocsl Você pode adicionar uma resposta para que os usuários futuros tenha mais de uma opção de ~gambiarra~ pra solucionar esse problema, caso removam o pseudo seletor ::shadow ainda teria outras opções para quem precisar futuramente, então acho válido sim

Comment: Veronse valeu a força, mas acredito que só o comentário já seja suficiente já que é algo bem simples... além disso, por vc já ter resolvido do jeito certo, acredito que nã vai aceitar a "gambiarra" como resposta rss